# Cassandra - dealing with multiple queries filtering on various subsets of fields

Tags: database, cassandra, data-modeling

My team is developing an application that has to store and read large amounts of data quickly. Therefore we were asked to use Cassandra.

We wrote down expected queries, and designed tables basing on them. Four of the biggest tables stored time series data, where partition key consisted of fields a, b and c, with timestamp t used as clustering key.

Unfortunately, client decided that he wants to be able to filter data in these four tables basing on any combination of these fields - something we did not design our application around. Now we are wondering how to modify the tables and queries, which is a bit of a problem as we lack someone with considerable Cassandra experience.

The stopgap solution was to use 'allow filtering' clause, but we are afraid of suffering a big efficiency hit. We have attempted to build a series of materialized views basing on tables in which partitioning key consisted only of the timestamp - seven views for each table, three with partitioning key consisting of field a/b/c, three more with partitioning keys ab/ac/bc, and a last one with PK abc. This does not work, as Cassandra allows the MV to only expand its partitioning key by one field over the base table, and does not allow for building MVs on MVs. We were considering adding indexes on the three fields, but this seems like a poor idea, as fields a, b and c have cardinalities ranging from tens to tens of thousands.

What would be the best solution in this case? Creating twenty-eight - seven for each of the four original tables - tables seems like a consistency nightmare. Or should we just give up on Cassandra, and fight to move to some other database?

Comment: look into SASI or the solr/elastic indexing options of cassandra?